# There is a dragon in Dawnstar,and I am 412/305 in weight and Lydia cant carry anymore,im in the Jarls Whitehouse at the moment!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was getting my reward from a quest but at that moment a dragon attacked I killed it and took everything but then I was overweight by 228 I have loads to Lydia and I'm stuck in the Jarls house as another one is flying around,I am now fifteen over weight so I still can't fast travel! What should I do,eat all the food?

Comment: Dump anything not important . . .

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Drop stuff.

Comment: There is no issue, you are doomed. Restarting the game is your better option...

Answer (score 7):

Ah, dragon bones, the bane of the explorer! You know you'll be able to make dragon armour some day, so why not save the bones, right? Except it takes a million years (±5%) to get smithing to level 100, and by then you'll have *so many bones* [Insert joke here]. **Just drop'em**; you'll probably have enough for three armour sets by the time you can craft with them, and by then dragons will be like flies to your mighty arsenal.

Answer (score 2):

Things you drop will stay there for a while. Days.

Just drop stuff and come back and get it later.